# Small style adjustments CV (resume class)

Tags: cv, resume

I want to change the check symbols in the upper text field to something more pleasing. How do I do it?

Also, I want to end the the text of the key points a bit earlier, so the whole thing looks more ordered.

[image: Example picture]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{resume}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
%------------------------------------------------

\name{Max Musti}

\address{geb. 19.09.1999 \\ Angerstr.~1 \\ 84444 Oberhausen} % Main address

%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % A secondary address (optional)

\address{(+00)~$\cdot$~000~$\cdot$~0000000 \\ abcd.fgerts@gmail.it} % Contact information

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    

    \begin{rSection}{Bildungsweg}
        
        \begin{rSubsection}{Dissertation}{ab Februar 2024}{Universität XXX
            }{}
            \item über \enquote{Das Leben des großen Huhns: Historie, sozialpolitische Aspekte} (Betreuer: Prof. Dr. Max Mustermann)
        \end{rSubsection}
        
        \begin{rSubsection}{M.A. Maschinenbau}{Mai 2020 -- März 2022}{West-östliche universität, Abschlussnote: 1.0}{}
            \item Masterarbeit über \enquote{hochwichtige Dinge, die meine Verwandten nicht interessieren} (Bewertung: 1,0, Betreuer: Prof. Dr. Betreuinskan Betreuski)
            \item intensive wissenschaftliche Auseinandersetzung Dingen, die meine Eltern nicht interessieren.
            \item Seminare zu Dingen die mich selbst häufig nicht übermäßig interessiert haben
        \end{rSubsection}
        
        
    \end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EXAMPLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{rSection}{Section Name}

%Section content\ldots

%\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not clear to me, what you mean. Can you please add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: I revised the question and attached a rather awkward screenshot that hopefully shows what I mean.

Comment: Fine. Where do you obtain the resume class from? Don‘t see it on ctan.org .

Comment: To analyze the margins I suggest using package layout, which shows all margins set as rectangles. Then it probably becomes evident, which parameter to adjust.

Comment: It's this template: https://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv

Comment: I used the layout package. What a nice package! (Sorry, I'm an amateur.) But how can  I use \textwidth just for certain lines, e.g. the one with the key points?

Comment: Fine. // If you don‘t know or have similar books on latex: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX. // Use {} to localize changes, i.e. confine them to certain lines. Consider using dedicated \newcommand macros to simplify input and standardize output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, that I can see, what `resume.cls` is doing, I can help you.

So, here is one way to do it, which redefines 2 macros defined in said style.

### 1 Changing the diamond

All you need to do is to `\renewcommand` this one; see the [symbol catalog](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) and make your choice, i.e. change the ding-value:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand{\addressSep}{\ding{54}}
```

### 2 Adjusting the right margin

The style uses a list-environment inside the `rSubsection` command. Lists accept layout relevant options, like rightmargin. So copy that code from the style, `\renewenvironment`, i.e. overwrite it :

- key is this line `\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em,\rightmargin=\RM}% <<< add right list margin`
- where I introduced `\newcommand\RM[0]{3cm}` to set the value

That's it (besides a straying comma, but that's a different question)

---

**P.S.:** I introduced the comma. Just remove it between the two margin-specifications like here:

```
\begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em \rightmargin=\RM}% <<< add right list margin
```

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
12pt,
]{resume}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}% <<< probably obsolete
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}

% ~~~ redefining the diamonds ~~~~~~~ <<< see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand{\addressSep}{\ding{54}}% <<< overwriting definition from resume.cls


% ~~~ redefining list-margins ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%     copy from resume.cls
%     \REnewcommand
\newcommand\RM[0]{3cm}% <<< simplification: just change the right list margin here
%
\renewenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 parameters: company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
    \textbf{#1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date to the right
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third parameter is empty, don't output the job title and location line
        \\ % Job title and location on a new line
        \textit{#3} \hfill \textit{#4} % Output job title and location
    }%
    \smallskip % Vertical whitespace
    \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em,\rightmargin=\RM}% <<< add right list margin
    % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5em} \vspace{-0.5em} % Reduce vertical spacing between items in the list for a tighter look
}{
    \end{list}
    \vspace{0.5em} % Vertical whitespace after the end of the list
}

%------------------------------------------------

\name{Max Musti}

\address{geb. 19.09.1999 \\ Angerstr.~1 \\ 84444 Oberhausen} % Main address

%\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % A secondary address (optional)

\address{(+00)~$\cdot$~000~$\cdot$~0000000 \\ abcd.fgerts@gmail.it} % Contact information

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    

    \begin{rSection}{Bildungsweg}
        
        \begin{rSubsection}{Dissertation}{ab Februar 2024}{Universität XXX
            }{}
            \item über \enquote{Das Leben des großen Huhns: Historie, sozialpolitische Aspekte} (Betreuer: Prof. Dr. Max Mustermann)
        \end{rSubsection}
        
        \begin{rSubsection}{M.A. Maschinenbau}{Mai 2020 -- März 2022}{West-östliche universität, Abschlussnote: 1.0}{}
            \item Masterarbeit über \enquote{hochwichtige Dinge, die meine Verwandten nicht interessieren} (Bewertung: 1,0, Betreuer: Prof. Dr. Betreuinskan Betreuski)
            \item intensive wissenschaftliche Auseinandersetzung Dingen, die meine Eltern nicht interessieren.
            \item Seminare zu Dingen die mich selbst häufig nicht übermäßig interessiert haben
        \end{rSubsection}
        
        
    \end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EXAMPLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\begin{rSection}{Section Name}

%Section content\ldots

%\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything works just fine! Thank you for your effort and the explanations.